# Cygwin terminal input disappearing after quitting vim

Tags: vim, cygwin

Using Cygwin, I tried creating and editing a file in Vim:

```
touch test | vim
```

This is obviously a mistake; something like `vim "$(touch test)"` has a better chance of actually working.  Nevertheless, this command throws the error:

> Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal.

And after this, Vim opens and I exit the program with `:q`.  Any subsequent commands I enter into the terminal are hidden from view until I restart Cygwin.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't understand what does a pipe `|` do in shell.

Pipe will take the pervious command's stdout as stdin to next command, in a subshell.

Your `touch foo` doesn't generate any output, what do you expect to happen? same for `vim "$(touch test)"`.

If you want to create a file and open it in vim in one shot, you can try:

```
touch foo && vim foo
```

If you want to edit it with vim anyway, actually, you can simply just:

```
vim foo
```

then save the buffer after your editing.

Comment: Understood, but this doesn't even remotely address my question.  I'm not asking how to create a file and edit in in vim - I'm interested in figuring out why the terminal input disappears after the process I described.  More specifically, I'm trying to figure out if this is *expected behavior* given the commands I entered, or a cygwin bug.

Comment: ok..@alex it is about the terminal setting/configs. I don't have much experience with windows OS, cygwin either. sorry.  On a linux box, if you want to reset terminal, you can do with stty command,  `stty sane`. you can give it a try on your cygwin.

Comment: No problem! For what it's worth, `stty sane` does appear to resolve the Cygwin issue - but I'm more interested in figuring out what's causing this to happen for my own erudition.